# How to move app icon to another page in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode8

Xcode is placing my app icon on the second page of icons in the iOS simulator.  Is there a way to move the app icon to the first page?  I've tried click and hold on the icon.  It switches to move/delete mode but when I try to move to the left it snaps back.

I'm developing an app extension and having to swipe left twice every time is getting old.  Thanks!

Comment: If you have a legitimate use case, file an enhancement request with Apple. This is not a Stack Overflow matter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do exactly what you're doing, but maybe more slowly or carefully. This works the same on the simulator as on a device, but doing it with a mouse is a little more fiddly than doing it with a fingertip.

Edit: This doesn't work any more. I'm leaving this answer up because it was the correct answer to the question when the question was asked.

Comment: Have you tried on a Xcode 14 simulator, doesn't seem possible

Answer (score 35):

I was troubled with this on iOS 16.2 (xcode 14.2), as the edition mode is triggered but you are not able to drag the apps on the screen. The solution I found is swiping right until you reach the App Library and from there you can easily drag and drop the apps trough your simulator.

Comment: You will then have a duplicate on the original page. This can be removed by clicking the (-) button (when in edit mode) and selecting "Remove from Home Screen". The one you placed on the correct page will still be there.

Comment: I can't seem to drag from the "App Library" to the screen-of-my-choice, only the right-most (or sometimes a new screen)

Is this something that can be addressed in the simulator via the toolset?

Comment: You should be able to drag the app from the App Library through all screens. Be aware that if the dragged app "touches" the screen border, it will be placed in the current screen. To drag it to the next screen, keep it near the simulator border without touching it.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed on Simulator v15 this works again but you still have to drag from the App Library (leaving multiple instances of your app on the screen!). The difference now is you have to be **holding down the option key** when selecting the app from the App Library.

Comment: The other thing I forgot to mention is that once you place the app where you want it, you can go back to the original instance and just choose "Remove from Home Screen" from edit mode and it will remove the original but leave your new one in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all applications on the second screen and save space for youur app on the first screen. When you'll install your app, it'll be on first screen